# How do I do the equivalent of "git diff --name-status" with jgit?

Tags: java, jgit

I want to get a list of changed/added/deleted files between revision XXXXXX and HEAD. This is what I have so far:

```
String oldHash = "a97e5553e37a25bd1a3c99eab303145baed08dbd";
Git git = Git.open(new File("/tmp/jgit"));
Repository repository = git.getRepository();
ObjectId old = repository.resolve(oldHash);
ObjectId head = repository.resolve("HEAD");

// how do i get the trees from the obj. id?
List<<DiffEntry> diffs = git.diff().setNewTree(null).setOldTree(null).call();

for(DiffEntry diff : diffs) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Is this the right way to go about it and if so, how do I get the trees required for git.diff() ?

Comment: This is a great question even though the OP specifically only asked about --name-status, because it applies to all jgit.Git.diff() type questions, for which IMHO examples are scarce and the API documentation oblique. So thanks! And thanks for the answers @[Kevin Sawicki](http://stackoverflow.com/users/687965/kevin-sawicki) and @[ktoso](http://stackoverflow.com/users/111024/ktoso) too!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the tree id for HEAD and the hash by calling:

```
ObjectId head = repository.resolve("HEAD^{tree}");
```

and for the revision id:

```
ObjectId old = repository.resolve(oldHash + "^{tree}");
```

Once you have the tree ids you can create the tree iterators and get the diffs:

```
ObjectReader reader = repository.newObjectReader();
CanonicalTreeParser oldTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();
oldTreeIter.reset(reader, oldId);
CanonicalTreeParser newTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();
newTreeIter.reset(reader, headId);
List<DiffEntry> diffs= git.diff()
                        .setNewTree(newTreeIter)
                        .setOldTree(oldTreeIter)
                        .call();
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a whirl tonight.

Comment: I've also found the tests for DiffCommand really helpful while implementing things around diffs - so I thought I'll share the link :-) http://git.eclipse.org/c/jgit/jgit.git/tree/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api/DiffCommandTest.java