# JGit Show remote changes like git diff --name-status master origin/master

Tags: java, git, jgit

I'm trying a bit with JGIT.
It's work very well, but I haven't found out how to show changes on a remote git before makeing a pull. 
In the terminal I solved my problem with the following steps:

1. `git fetch`
2. `git diff --name-status master origin/master`

How can I get the remote changes with JGit? Has anyone a idea?

I think the thread [How do I do the equivalent of "git diff --name-status" with jgit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520682/how-do-i-do-the-equivalent-of-git-diff-name-status-with-jgit) can help, but I don't know how to get the remote HEAD.

Answer (score 2):

I found out how to get the remote HEAD (FETCH_HEAD).
Now my Code is as follows:

```
git.fetch().call();
Repository repo = git.getRepository();      
ObjectId fetchHead = repo.resolve("FETCH_HEAD^{tree}");
ObjectId head = repo.resolve("HEAD^{tree}");

ObjectReader reader = repo.newObjectReader();
CanonicalTreeParser oldTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();
oldTreeIter.reset(reader, head);
CanonicalTreeParser newTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();
newTreeIter.reset(reader, fetchHead);
List<DiffEntry> diffs= git.diff().setShowNameAndStatusOnly(true)
                        .setNewTree(newTreeIter)
                        .setOldTree(oldTreeIter)
                        .call();
for(DiffEntry entry : diffs) {
    System.out.println(entry.toString());
}
```

It shows me remote changes like I wanted, but it works not correct. If I create a new File in my working-copy and commit the file (without to push), then the diff show me that the new file is deleted in the FETCH_HEAD.
How can I filter this false delete messages?