# List remote changes in git repository using JGit (a real diff)

Tags: git, jgit

I'm trying to list all changes that occurred remotely without computing changes made in local. In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435714/jgit-show-remote-changes-like-git-diff-name-status-master-origin-master) its demonstrated how to do a diff against remote, like the code below:

```java
git.fetch().call();
Repository repo = git.getRepository();      
ObjectId fetchHead = repo.resolve("FETCH_HEAD^{tree}");
ObjectId head = repo.resolve("HEAD^{tree}");

ObjectReader reader = repo.newObjectReader();
CanonicalTreeParser oldTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();
oldTreeIter.reset(reader, head);
CanonicalTreeParser newTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();
newTreeIter.reset(reader, fetchHead);
List<DiffEntry> diffs= git.diff().setShowNameAndStatusOnly(true)
                        .setNewTree(newTreeIter)
                        .setOldTree(oldTreeIter)
                        .call();
for(DiffEntry entry : diffs) {
    System.out.println(entry.toString());
}
```

The problem is that if we use a diff, local changes are computed as "reverse" remote changes. For example, if we add a file in local, it's computed as deleted from remote, since it doesn't exist there. In the same way, if I delete a file locally it's listed as a remote addition.
How do you ignore this cases? Actually it's not exactly an issue of jgit, if you show me how to do using git commands I can find a way with jgit myself...

**Edit**: The triple dot is the solution in raw git, like this:

```
git diff --name-status HEAD...origin/master
```

Now I need to represent this command in JGit. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I thought may be we can reference the remote branch's head before we do a git fetch. as shown below

```
Repository repository = git.getRepository();
    String branch = repository.getBranch();
    ObjectId head = repository.resolve("refs/heads/"+branch+"^{tree}");
    git.fetch();
    System.out.println(branch);

    Config storedConfig = repository.getConfig();

    Set<String> remotes = storedConfig.getSubsections("remote");

    System.out.println(remotes);

    ObjectId fetchHead = repository.resolve("FETCH_HEAD^{tree}");

    ObjectReader reader = repository.newObjectReader();
    CanonicalTreeParser oldTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();
    oldTreeIter.reset(reader, head);
    CanonicalTreeParser newTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();
    newTreeIter.reset(reader, fetchHead);
    List<DiffEntry> diffs= git.diff().setShowNameAndStatusOnly(true)
            .setNewTree(newTreeIter)
            .setOldTree(oldTreeIter)
            .call();
    for(DiffEntry entry : diffs) {
        System.out.println(entry.toString());
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the answer after asking at he EGit forum. [Here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1692916/#msg_1692916) you can find more details. Basically, the triple dot notation in diff means `git diff $(git-merge-base A B) B`, that is, diff between (merge-base of A and B) and B

So, the solution is to take the base of "head" and "fetch_head" and then perform a diff of base and fetch_head.

To get the base commit, take a look at the project [gitective](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/gitective/blob/master/org.gitective.core/src/test/java/org/gitective/tests/CommitBaseTest.java).