# JGit get pulled files

Tags: java, git, jgit

I have one repository in two different folders ( `folder1` and `folder2`). Within repositories has a `"oldFile"` file

In the `folder1` I do the following steps:

```
echo 123 > oldFile
touch newFile
git add newFile oldFile
git commit -m "Change the oldFile from folder1 and add the newFile" oldFile newFile
git push origin master
```

After that, in the `folder2` I do next steps:

```
echo zxc > oldFile;
git add oldFile;
git commit oldFile -m "Change oldFile from folder2"
```

In this case I want to get a merge conflict

And I want to see pulled files. I got the example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26170467/3452146).

```
ObjectId oldHead = repository.resolve("HEAD^{tree}"); //save old objectId

PullResult pullResult = pullCommand.setProgressMonitor(new TextProgressMonitor(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out))).call();

ObjectId head = repository.resolve("HEAD^{tree}");

ObjectReader reader = repository.newObjectReader();
CanonicalTreeParser oldTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();
oldTreeIter.reset(reader, oldHead);
CanonicalTreeParser newTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();
newTreeIter.reset(reader, head);
List<DiffEntry> diffs= git.diff()
                    .setNewTree(newTreeIter)
                    .setOldTree(oldTreeIter)
                    .call();
```

In `pullResult.getMergeResult().getMergeConflicts()` I have only file `oldFile` and the `diffs` collection is empty.

In a simple case ( when I don't change the "OldFile" from `folder2` ) the diffs collection is not empty - it has 1 the file "newFile" and `pullResult.getMergeResult().getMergeConflicts()` is emtpy ( it's obviously).

What do I do wrong? I want to get conflicted files and successful pulled files.

Comment: Doesn't the `git pull` command show you file names that had conflicts along with conflict error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer. Need use

`ObjectId head = git.getRepository().resolve("refs/remotes/origin/HEAD^{tree}");`

instead of

`ObjectId head = repository.resolve("HEAD^{tree}");`